How to create an upgrade script that runs without a password
I installed Ubuntu on my sons laptop that he will be using for school, as such I don't want him to have the password just yet. I would still like him to be able to run these three commands to update, upgrade and clean up his computer,
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get upgrade
sudo apt autoremove
I have created a script that runs these commands but it asks for the password when the first command runs. I have seen that you can set ALL = NOPASSWD in the /etc/sudoers file but I don't want that either because if I understand correctly this would allow him to run any command without the password which would defeat the purpose of not giving him the password.
